# I deleted by mistake my AWS IAM user: how to recover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Stupidly enough, I did delete by mistake my default AWS IAM user!

I used it for example do `aws s3 sync`...

Now the error I get is:

```
$ aws s3 sync build/ s3://mybucket.mydomain.com
fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjects operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Is there a way to recover?

I think I need instructions how to create a new user with the sufficient roles to enable my local aws cli to be able to do `aws s3 sync ...`

**UPDATE**: I did just create a new user on my AWS console, and added a policy (to start with) to list my bucket. The problem is I don't know how to *attach* my aws cli to that new user... :-(

Comment: No, you need to create a new user - note that any policy that directly referenced that user is now broken as well since they store an internal identifier that changes when you delete and re-create a user.

Comment: Just create new one, under same IAM name.

Comment: @Marcin: I do not even remember the exact IAM name... In my ~/.aws/credentials I only have `[default]`...

Comment: @luk2302: I did suspect something similar... Can you point me to some documentation how to create a new user with the sufficient roles to enable my local aws cli to be able to do `aws s3 sync ...`?

Comment: If you are the only person using this AWS Account, then add the `Admin` IAM Role to your IAM User. That will grant complete access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the only person using this AWS Account, then add the `AdministratorAccess` Policy to your IAM User. That will grant complete access.

Then, in the **Security credentials** tab of the IAM User click **Create access key**. Copy the Access Key and Secret Access Key.

On the command line, run `aws configure` and provide those keys to configure the user.

Test with: `aws s3 ls`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I feel quite dumb... How do I add the `Admin` IAM Role to my IAM user, exactly? Should I start from the `users` section or from the `roles` section?

Comment: Oops. It should actually be the `AdministratorAccess` **Policy**. Click **Add Permissions** from the Permissions tab in the User, then find and add that policy.

Comment: It's not a SO best practice, but I want to THANK YOU ! You saved my day! :-)